# How to Add multiple EditText in Arralist In Android Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, arraylist

I want to add multiple EditText in my Canvas but m getting error something float EditText() in EditText can not be Applied something float values cant not be added.

Here Is my Code For That

```
ArrayList<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();

if (c.getImage() == 2) {

        editTexts.add(new EditText(c.getEdittext(),xtouch1,yTouch1,mPaint));// m getting error at this point
        for (EditText l : editTexts) {

            canvas.drawText(c.getEdittext(),xTouch1,yTouch1,mPaint);             

        }
        c.setImage(0);
        line_c = 0;
```

Thanks For Help In Advance

Comment: Any reason for downvote? You should comment when downvoting so asker can improve the quality of question as per SO standards.

Comment: Information is not enough for someone to look into your problem, kindly provide stacktrace also.